# Building a table with groups and grouped items (not aggregated)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to build a table which needs the following layout

[Header - contains various columns of data]

[Items - Contains data related by an ID, not related in any way to the header columns]

[Blank Row]

[The next group item]

Lets say we have 3 tables...[tblPurchases], [tblLocations], [tblItems]
I need a new header for every item in [tblPurchases] and then i need all the items from [tblItems] linked by [PurchasePKID] listed under each header item.

now i also need to do the following.....
[tblPurchases] may or may not have a [LocationPKID]
If FALSE then the header rows will collect data from [tblPurchases]
If TRUE then the header rows will collect data from both [tblPurchases] and [tblLocations].

There are no Aggregate functions at all, it simply retreives data from the table.

This is the basic functionality im going to test and im interested in how someone else approaches this, the actual query i have right now is a little more complex than this example, it also needs to check other tables depending on the Items data and output yet another level of items for each item, but this example will give me a good idea of how to do that using other methods (hopefully).

My current method uses nested cursors to iterate  through the headers, items and sub items and builds the output table 1 piece at a time. its over 350 lines long which is really to big so i hope you guys can help me out here :)

Thanks

Comment: Add sample table data, the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt, and describe what's wrong with it.

Comment: [tblPurchases] (ID, LocationID, Data), [tblLocations] (ID, Data), [tblItems] (ID, PurchaseID, Data). This is just a test to find another method of doing this. im not too good at sql so im trying to get some ideas. my current Query works fine its just a little slow so im looking for another method.

Comment: The output should be for each item in purchases add a header then check the items table for the related purchase id and list the items, so it should be something like [HeaderRow1] then [Items List1] then [HeaderRow2] etc etc, the columns are not the same in this output table, the header and items rows do NOT have matching column names, it needs to be built manually (unless there is a way to do it i dont know about)

Comment: Look at GROUPING SETS

Comment: i was looking at grouping sets rollups and cubes but im not sure if or which one i might use, and groups require Aggregate functions if im not mistaken? im not calculating anything, im just collating data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use [AdventureWorks2012]
go

declare @worktable table
(rectype int, salesorderid int,detail varchar(132))


insert into @worktable
Select  1,
        [SalesOrderID],
        concat([OrderDate],' ', p.[PersonType],' ',p.[Title] , ' ', p.[FirstName], ' ', p.[LastName])
from    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] sh
join    [Sales].[Customer]   sc on sc.customerid = sh.CustomerID
join    [Person].[Person] p on p.[BusinessEntityID] = sc.PersonID
where   SalesOrderID in (43659,43660,43661,43662,43663,43664)

insert into @worktable
Select  3,
        [SalesOrderID],
        ''
from    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] sh
join    [Sales].[Customer]   sc on sc.customerid = sh.CustomerID
join    [Person].[Person] p on p.[BusinessEntityID] = sc.PersonID
where   SalesOrderID in (43659,43660,43661,43662,43663,43664)

insert into @worktable
select  2,
        sd.[SalesOrderDetailID],
        concat(sd.[ProductID], ' ',p.[Name],' ',sd.[LineTotal])  
from    [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] sd
join    [Production].[Product] p on p.ProductID = sd.[ProductID]
where   sd.[SalesOrderDetailID] in (43659,43660,43661,43662,43663,43664)

select  case 
        when rectype = 1 then 'Header'
        when rectype = 2 then 'Detail'
        else 'Blank'
        end type,
        salesorderid, detail 
from    @worktable
order   by salesorderid,rectype
```

Comment: Hi Paul S. Since I set this hare running I thought I would illustrate my thinking using adventure works data. Basically I am creating a work table with some key fields and and a detail block using a record type to sequence the output.

Comment: This looks promising, so initially this is going to build a single table with all the headers and items not organized and then organize them using a common ID and RecType, I think this is worth testing thanks. ill post back after i give it a try.

Comment: Using this method, can i add a blank row between the headers and last items easily? or would it be easier to do that from the application code that this table is used on?

Comment: Yes. You just need to use the record type to order the output. Can't comment on your app.

Comment: This method worked perfectly, i had to use 4 temporary tables in the end as each table required a key reference from the last table so i used Inner Joins on them and then i tracked the Parent Child relationship through some extra columns i added and sorted on these id fields to organize everything, it worked great........The Old SP was taking 7-10 seconds to run and this one is taking 0-1 seconds to run........Thanks

Comment: the whole thing was achieved with 4 table declarations and 6 insert statements, nothing complicated :D

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you properly, you do NOT want to get the result TABLE.
You want to get REPORT wiht some tables which contains different columns (HEAER, ITEMS...).

That is your solution with cursors is not a bad idea.

Comment: yes, i cannot use a basic query to output the result i need since there is no single column structure, im currently using cursors to loop certain tables and then build the output table up row by row, im just wandering whether there is another way to do this.... sounds like there might not be by your response :)

Comment: there can be solution if output result as a text with subquery and groupping sets for example, but it can be monstrous. 
declare t1 table (c varchar(10), c2 varchar(10))

insert into t1 values('a', 'a')
insert into t1 values('a', 'b')
insert into t1 values('a', 'c')

select 
  case
   when s.c is null then 'header'
   when s.c2 is null then 'subheader or something else'
   else s.c + '|' + s.c2
  end
 from 
  (select t.c, t.c2
   from t1 t
   group by rollup(t.c, t.c2)
  ) s
 order by s.c, s.c2

Comment: I think this is similar to the code given by P.Salmon.....im going to give this a try, follow the progress on P.Salmon's Answer  if you have some more ideas, Thanks. btw my current SP is monstrous (350 lines) so its ok  if it has to be big, just as long as its fast :)